# use array of indexes to filter another array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 1 array and 1 set,set `Indexes` and array is `Names`.

Indexes contains various numbers which are basically indexes of random elements of `Names`  array.I want to filter Names array based on indexes in Indexes array i.e push specific elements of Names array to another array whose indexes are present in the Indexes array.

What I am doing is:

```
const Indexes =[0,1]
const Names=["Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4"]

const filteredNames = Indexes.map(item => Names[item]);
```

Output should be:

```
filteredNames=["Test1","Test2"]
```

but its not working.Any leads on this?

Comment: What is not working? your code results in `['Test1', 'Test2']` when printing `filteredNames`

Comment: add `console.log(filteredNames)` at end of the code

Comment: I checked it code was works perfectly as your Output

Comment: updated the ques now,Indexes is a set not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Indexes is a Set, then you just need `Array.from` function:

```js
const Indexes =new Set([0,1])
const Names=["Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4"]

const filteredNames = Array.from(Indexes)
    .map(item => Names[item]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it right

```js
const Indexes =[0,1]
const Names=["Test1","Test2","Test3","Test4"]

const filteredNames = Indexes.map(item => Names[item]);
console.log(filteredNames)
```